# How to fit React Modal size children?

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, react-modal

I am trying to load a dynamic login page with React Modal. Is there a way to make React Modal resize to the size of its child elements?

```
//App.js
import "./styles/app.scss";
import Layout from './options/Layout'
import Login from './Components/Login'
import { useState } from "react";
import Modal from 'react-modal'
function App() {
  const [OpenModal, setOpenModal] = useState(false)
  return (
    <div id="app" className="App">
      <Layout>
        
        <button onClick = {() => setOpenModal(true)}>open modal</button>
        <Modal isOpen = {OpenModal}>
        <Login/>
        </Modal>
      </Layout>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

```
//login.scss

.login {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 300px;
  height: 280px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #5c8fc2;
  border-radius: 30px;
}
.login_top {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: -40px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  color: whitesmoke;
}
.login_register_container {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

button {
  margin-right: 12px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

I want to dynamically manage the size according to the child element.

I've tried several methods, but without success. How to fit modal's component to child element???

Comment: login.scss is the css of the login page.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the developer tools you can see that the content grows because they have applied some styles to the modal.

```
position: absolute;
inset:40
```

inset is same as

```
top: 40px;
left: 40px;
right: 40px;
bottom: 40px;
```

If you want your content to be exactly the same size as your content, you can remove the right and bottom from the styles.

```
<ReactModal
      isOpen={true}
      contentLabel="Minimal Modal Example"
      className="Modal"
    >
      <div>
        <div style={{ height: '500px' }}>Some content</div>
      </div>
      <button onClick={() => {}}>Close Modal</button>
    </ReactModal>
```

CSS:

```
.Modal {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  left: 40px;  
  background-color: papayawhip;
}
```

You will lose equal spacing on all sides of the modal if you do this though.

Here is an example. https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-vxe3cn